# Making a static lib target with variable dependencies with CMake

Tags: cmake, static-linking

So I have a static library A which can have a bunch of settings turned on, depending on the compiling configuration. I have these settings pushed out to an IMPORT file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
MESSAGE(STATUS "***Making A With FOO***")
add_definitions(-DFOO)
include_directories("$ENV{FOO_ROOT}/Includes")
link_directories("$ENV{FOO_ROOT}/Libraries")
```

called with

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project(A)
if (FOO)
IMPORT(CMakeList.Foo.txt)
ADD_LIBRARY(A STATIC a.cpp)
```

Because the library is static, it appears that I have to populate these settings to any other project in the chain that exports them...is there a way to get the library to do its own linking to other static libraries, or is the only way around this to make the library shared?

Edit: I should add that I'm building this as part of a subdirs project

Comment: I'm confused about what you want.  For example, when you say "these settings", which are you referring to specifically?  Also, I don't see the `IMPORT` command anywhere in the CMake docs... what does it do?

Comment: @SethMMorton IMPORT essentially runs the cmake script at the target at the place of the import call (good for defining MACROs and modular definitions)